# does casting a buffer to a uint32_t cause unaligned access

Tags: c, networking, serialization

if I have a struct that was serialized over the network, and then received as a char buffer, can I safely cast a part of that buffer to a `uint32_t` or can it cause unaligned memory access due to the padding being removed by the serialization process? i.e.

```c
typedef struct foo{
    uint8_t y;
    uin32_t x;
} foo;

void sendFoo(foo *f) {
    //create a buffer to use
    //...
    buffer[0] = f->y;
    uint32_t x = htonl(foo->x);
    memcpy(buffer+1, (char*)&x, sizeof(uint32_t));
    //...
}

foo recvFoo() {
    //create some foo and a buffer for recv to work with
    //...
    f.y = buffer[0];
    f.x = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)(buffer+1)); //potential unaligned access error?
    //...
}
```

If this does cause an error then how am I supposed to deserialize this struct?

Comment: And there is no need to use htonl and ntohl, people often overuse them. Instead add the lowest to highest byte to the buffer: u32 & 0xFF, u32 & 0xFF00 etc, and do the reverse when recieving. That will work on all machines regardless of endianess.

Comment: @Fredrik thanks I fixed the example, code. I'm leaving the question up as there's still a discussion going on and I'm confused on who's right

Comment: you and me both fredrik, i cant believe i forgot memcpy exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee from the information provided that `buffer+1` is correctly aligned for a 32-bit read/write. This isn't a problem on a x86/x64 (except maybe for performance reasons), but it could be on other platforms.

Just like you avoided the issue by using `memcpy` on the sender side, you could sidestep the issue by using `memcpy` on the receiver side if you wanted portability.

(I'm assuming `buffer` is a `char*`.)

Comment: you assumed correctly, sorry for not including that info :). So how would you go about actually deserializing something like this?

Comment: Added to my answer

Comment: Just to be clear, using `memcpy` would likely be even slower. But it buys you portability, if that's something you want.